# Would formatting my iMac fix my failing drive?

Tags: imac, driver, disk-format

I have been dealing with this problem for few months, I was using bootcamp on my iMac late 2013, and after a while its driver corrupted using too much disk space and slowing down. So I deleted it and created a new bootcamp partition but my problems didn't end there. Every time I shut down my computer its windows files would corrupt again making me redownload windows. And few days ago this corruption affected my main iMac drive too. I can repair the disk through disk utility because its giving me exit code 8, my internet recovery mode is giving me code -2002f and its startup is extremely slow ( only the part where you enter your password and log in) everything else is fine. Startup problem is the same problem i had with the bootcamp. I was getting black screens during startups. I wasn't able to delete my bootcamp partition until today because the disk utility didn't let me to do it. I deleted it through terminal and now I am dealing with my main drive corruption. I plan to sell this iMac very soon due to educational fees and I want to fix this before I sell it. I am currently trying to log into single user mode but its keep failing to mount disk0s2 and there is a small white circle with a cross on the screen. How can I fix this? Would formatting my iMac solve all my driver problems?

Answer (score 1):

The 2013 iMac was offered with 1TB hard drive, Fusion drive, or SSD. The first two of these use mechanical spinning platter hard drives, which are expected to have a limited life before failing.

After six years, it's likely that the drive is failing, and so Erasing or repartitioning it won't help. Replacing the drive is possible, but "[moderately difficult](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2638+Hard+Drive+Replacement/28781)".

Comment: so should i just throw away my computer? I am erasing it right now and I really need some money for educational fees.

Comment: also i bought it in 2015 its been 3-4 years shouldn't that be early? I was able to log into internet recovery via my phones internet and now im deleting the main disk0s2, I hope this goes well before i sell it

Comment: You can certainly try erasing it and reinstalling the OS: however, something must have caused whatever 'corruption' occurred on both Windows and Mac partitions, which suggests a hardware problem.

Comment: you can always take it to an Apple Store or an Apple Authorized repair shop and get the drive replaced.